# Change UIPageViewController page programmatically without reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController (Holding two UIViewControllers and a UITableViewController) to navigate around my app. I have added buttons to move from one page to another, using the `setViewControllers` method which is suggested in many stack overflow questions. However, if I start on view controller B, swipe to view controller A, and then use the suggested setViewControllers method to return to view controller B, it does not simply return to the page, it loads a new instance of view controller B. This is a problem because I am displaying data retrieved from the Internet in view controller B, and so havig to retrieve this every time is very inneficient. 
Now I know it is possible because snapchat, tinder, and fling all do it. Unless they just store the data that is to be displayed and load that every time

Comment: "I am using a UIPageViewController (Holding two UIViewControllers and a UITableViewController)" Impossible. A UIPageViewController has just one view controller at a time.

Comment: "Unless they just store the data that is to be displayed and load that every time". Sure. Model-view-controller! Do NOT store persistent data in a view controller. A view controller tells a view how to display model data. Store the data in a model, and store it in a way that does not rely on the view controller to persist - because, as you've discovered, they do not necessarily persist.

Comment: Thanks Matt, excuse my ignorance, but are we talking about a data model in core data? The thing that struck me as surprising is that if you go on tinder and scroll down a table, and then go to another view and then return, it returns at the same offset as you left. So would they even be storing things like this?

Comment: That's a navigation controller. It is a stack, so when you push and pop you unwind back to the same view controller. This is a page view controller; it doesn't work like that at all. You have to make a new view controller every time the page changes.

Comment: You've misunderstood what I meant, the pageViewController scrolls horizontally between navigation controllers that hold table view controllers. And when you scroll from one page to another it remembers at what offset the table view was left. This makes sense for normal scrolling, because the view controllers are loaded into the iPhone memory and kept there, but when you perform the setViewControllers method  it would ordinarily create a new instance of the navigation controller (and child table view controller) and scroll to it, therefore resetting the tableView offset

Comment: Okay, good discussion, and now I understand the picture and am ready with a positive suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your elaboration in the comments, you have noticed that the scrolling style of page view controller does happen to cache the adjacent view controllers. But that is an implementation detail, and you should not depend on it. It sounds to me like you are using a page view controller inappropriately, especially since you have only three "pages". I would suggest one of these:

- A tab bar controller. Again, this has the advantage that all the tab bar controller's children stay alive.
- A scroll view, forming the basis of your own custom parent view controller. You can just put all three "pages" as contained views side by side, and scroll. This has the even bigger advantage that scrolling just works (though you can make it work for the tab bar controller too) and that you are in total charge so once again the children all stay alive.

Comment: Thanks for persevering with me Matt! It sounds like your second suggestion is probably what I'm after, I'm very keen to keep the swiping navigation from the page view controller.

Comment: You can do a swiping navigation with a tab bar controller. But I'm not sure it presents much advantage over a simple horizontal paging scroll view.

Comment: It would certainly be easier for me to implement, how do I facilitate scrolling in a tab bar controller?

Comment: As I explain in my book, using this example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m But the scroll view is much easier; I hope you realize that. :) With the scroll view, you are just doing what the page view controller was doing, since it _is_ a scroll view when in scroll style - except that you would always have the caching.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Shall forge ahead with the scroll view

Comment: They are very simple. See my book for a good intro: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html What you want is a "paging" scroll view, so that the user can see exactly one subview at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt's comments and answer, I now know that a UIPageViewController doesn't persist the Child View Controllers in memory, so I used a UIScrollView instead. It's actually a lot easier to implement than the UIPageViewController anyway. The following code sets up what I needed

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    var scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width*3, self.view.bounds.height)
    scrollView.pagingEnabled=true
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    var scrollView2 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    scrollView2.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
    scrollView2.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width, 2*self.view.bounds.height)
    scrollView2.pagingEnabled=true
    scrollView2.bounces=false
    scrollView2.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=false
    scrollView2.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false
    scrollView.addSubview(scrollView2)

    var view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    view1.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(view1)
    //Add View controller 1 to view1

    var view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    view2.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    scrollView2.addSubview(view2)
    //Add view controller 2 to view2

    var view3 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    view3.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellowColor()
    scrollView2.addSubview(view3)
    //Add view controller 3 to view3

    var view4 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(2*view.bounds.width, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    view4.backgroundColor=UIColor.orangeColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(view4)
    //Add view controller 4 to view4

}`
```